# How can i customize UILabel for image display?

Tags: iphone, image, uilabel, customization

I want to customize UILabel control.

For example,

```
lblName.text = @"Zotiger";
```

then label shows Zotiger normally.

And if i set its text with some special characters (in my case, * is a special character for replacing with image)

```
lblName.text = @"***";
lblPhone.text =  @"***-****-****";
```

then label shows three icons as below image.

[image: star text will be replaced love icon]

How can i customize UILabel simply? Is there any open source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its simple, you can use certain Unicode characters in your string, and the iPhone will display them as Emoji

see this link for [heart unicode](http://www.easyapns.com/category/just-for-fun)

in your case for red heart :`\ue022`

Comment: If i want to replace customized icon (no certain Unicode character for example i want replace * with tiger icon), then how can i implement that?

Comment: you have to parse your text i.e. simply use if-else condition, if(label.text==@"*") then { label.text=assign unicode character}

Comment: Thanks. But as above image, HP text field has some different colors, i want a some customized label control.